# Has no default translation and R is not being generated

Tags: android, git, android-launcher

**Hello all !**

I am trying to compile the Trebuchet Launcher which is an open source one. The problem is that I keep getting compiling errors on strings which have no default translation, on top of that one R is not generated. 
So after the xml file fails, I get errors from resources that are not found.
Using Eclipse.

**What I have Tried :**

Went to the project Properties and Ignored the MissingTranslation, it still did not work.

Checked the xml files if they were missing any lines or if they were corrupted somehow, still they seem ok.

Checked various suggestions on kind of related questions here on stackoverflow, but still no luck.

**Git Link on the Launcher**

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Trebuchet

**To give you all an idea**

```
[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] warning: string 'accessibility_search_button' has no default translation.
[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] warning: string 'accessibility_voice_search_button' has no default translation.
[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] warning: string 'all_apps_cling_add_item' has no default translation.
[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] warning: string 'all_apps_cling_title' has no default translation.

[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] C:\Users\Arlind\trebouche\AndroidManifest.xml:92: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme').
[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] 
[2016-01-19 20:14:46 - ToggleWeightWatcher] C:\Users\Arlind\trebouche\AndroidManifest.xml:110: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme').
```

Comment: Project link that you posted has different strings file for different languages. Therefore you also have to create different strings.xml

Comment: hmmm what do you mean exactly with different strings.xml ?                 Because the way I see it there are values- language prefix folders with strings.xml in them !

Comment: for every language that you want your app to run in you have to create strings.xml for each language with language suffix

Comment: Yep, but the launcher already has different folders for specific languages with strings.xml in them ?

Comment: yes but if you add any extra string then you have to add them in all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml line 113 mentions:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme"
```

This style if you use search is not defined anywhere in the res/ folder (only inside the WallpaperPicker res/ folder). Also note the Android.mk file which is what it seems a makefile for building the project. This file defines as resources dir:

```
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/WallpaperPicker/res $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
```

so if you build the project using this makefile the build will probably succeed. Else you have to specify the "Theme" style inside the res/ folder by creating a style.xml file

Answer (score 2):

**1/ The translations:**

You have to set the translation in your res forders.

You will find folders for the differents languages already set
andin each of them you have the xml file: string.xml.

In this file you will have to set the translation of accessibility_search_button, accessibility_voice_search_button, all_apps_cling_add_item and all_apps_cling_title.

[image]

**2/ The styles:**

In your style.xml file you have to create the theme "Theme" because you're apparently trying to use it but it's not set yet.

Hope it helps.