# Facebook strings has no default translation

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got this error today trying to run an app with Facebook SDK attached into it.

```
Warning:string 'com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_continue_as_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_log_out_action_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_continue_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_continue_as_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_log_out_action_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_share_button_text_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_as_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_send_button_text_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_cancel_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_send_button_text_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_as_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_cancel_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_share_button_text_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_continue_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_title_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_title_m2gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_tooltip_default_f1gender' has no default translation.
Warning:string 'com_facebook_tooltip_default_m2gender' has no default translation.
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I'm trying to figure out why but I didn't try to ask for another string language than English. In the case of need, this is my app Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ".chillout"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my project Gradle.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has no default translation and R is not being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874637/has-no-default-translation-and-r-is-not-being-generated)

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate, it's an issue specific with Facebook SDK and great candidate for its own issue

Comment: I tried to upload the bug to Facebook SDK but it asked for an access token, how can I get the access token if I can not launch the app!?

Comment: Hey @I'lFollio have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: @Tony kind of, I downgrade to 4.23.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(As of July 11, 2017)

Roll back to the previous version, which is 4.23.0, seems to be working fine. I.e.

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.+'
```

The latest release 4.24.0 seems to be problematic in many ways on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same `com_facebook` warnings while building my app, but without the errors. So my guess is that the warnings and the errors are not related to each other.

In any case, I got rid of the `com_facebook` warnings by adding a file `res/values/facebook-strings.xml` containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_continue_f1gender">Continue</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_continue_m2gender">Continuee</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_action_f1gender">Log out</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_action_m2gender">Log out</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button_f1gender">Log out</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button_m2gender">Log out</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_as_f1gender">Logged in as</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_as_m2gender">Logged in as</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender">Logged in using Facebook</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_m2gender">Logged in using Facebook</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_send_button_text_f1gender">Send</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_send_button_text_m2gender">Send</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_share_button_text_f1gender">Share</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_share_button_text_m2gender">Share</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_cancel_f1gender">Cancel</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_cancel_m2gender">Cancel</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_continue_as_f1gender">Continue</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_continue_as_m2gender">Continue</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_title_f1gender">Confirm</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_title_m2gender">Confirm</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_tooltip_default_f1gender">Default</string>
  <string name="com_facebook_tooltip_default_m2gender">Default</string>
</resources>
```

Not sure whether the above "default translations" make sense, but I never saw them anyway. (The warnings were a result of a cordova plugin that I didn't want to mess with).

Comment: I got the same in Xamarin, your solution helped me but yes - those were just warnings covering other errors. Thanks!

Comment: Me too. I just dont understand why this started happening. It only happened after I upgraded VS2017 to 15.4.2!

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Facebook.Android 4.26.0 solved the problem