# Android/Facebook missing default translation 'warning' errors

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

From nowhere, my `Xamarin Forms` solution has generated 22 errors all in an Android project, all complaining that lots of '`com_facebook_XXXX has no default translation`'.
I have no idea what has caused this and googling the individual errors doesnt seems to turn anything relevant up.

[image]

I can see in `Resource.Designer.cs` that these constants are defined:

```
public const int com_facebook_smart_login_confirmation_title_m2gender = 2131230763;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f080016
public const int com_facebook_tooltip_default = 2131230742;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f08002c
public const int com_facebook_tooltip_default_f1gender = 2131230764;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f08002d
public const int com_facebook_tooltip_default_m2gender = 2131230765;
```

But what do I do with them?

Has anyone seen this before or know what has caused it?

Thanks

**Edit:**
Note, I'm using VS2017 here for development/build/compilation

**EDIT2**
I've switched branches to one I haven't touched in weeks (and was working fine on all platforms) and that is throwing the same errors so I dont think its code related. I did, however, upgrade VS2017 to the latest version (15.4.2) yesterday!

Comment: Which facebook package are you installing for your app?

Comment: Hi Grace, I'm using the official Facebook Android SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk but haven't updraded or changed anything regarding the DLL i'm referencing.

Comment: Didn't you install any package for Xamarin? The SDK you provided is for Java Android.

Comment: Ooops, wrong URL. I'm using the DLL reference from here: https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid.. However, I've switched branches to one I haven't touched in weeks and that is throwing the same errors so I dont think its code related. I did, however, upgrade VS2017 to the latest version yesterday!

Comment: According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938052/facebook-strings-has-no-default-translation), it seems to be the issue of facebook android sdk, which version is your installed package?

Comment: OK. so I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 completely and downgraded the version to 15.4.0 and those "errors" are there simply as warnings but the solution still builds. Looks like for some reason they are getting interpreted as errors in the latest VS release!

Comment: Really? Are you sure that you didn't select the option that `Treat warnings as errors` for your project in VS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following:

**Rollback to previous version in gradle:**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.+'
```

**Add a new file under *res/values/*:** This file must contain  tag as root with `<string>` tags like-

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_continue_f1gender">Continue</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't changed any versions and I'm using VS2017 for dev/test/build

Comment: Sorry, can't help in VS2017.